# Formatação de Hora

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que dividi uma String para escrever a mesma no formato de hora. Porém se coloco 102330 ao invés de me retornar 10:23:30 ele me traz 1:02:33 sendo que se coloco 112126 ele formata corretamente para 11:21:26. Se alguém souber me ajudar agradeço.

```
StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder();
                                    format.append(hora.substring(0, 2)).
                                            append(":").append(hora.substring(2, 4)).
                                            append(":").append(hora.substring(4, 6));
                                    System.out.println("Hora: " +format);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está correto, provavelmente há um espaço no início do texto 102330.

Tente debugar a função ou faça um simples sysout com o valor original para ver o espaço.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Utilizei um Pattern para eliminar os espaços e funcionou normalmente